# SAS: do loop help: variable =1 from start of by group until marker =1

Tags: sas, do-loops

In SAS, I have data that is sorted by time. For the first n minutes, a marker variable is marked 0 then changes to 1. This occurs within a 'by' variable. I want to create a new variable that =1 for each minute from the start of the 'by' group observations until the marker variable gets to 1. I have tried dozens of do loop combinations and have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example data set... what you want it to look like in the end?

Comment: Example data is necessary for this question to be a good question, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

From a data set like this:

```
by_var marker
A      0
A      0
A      1
B      0
B      0
B      1
```

You can get a data set that looks like this (if each observation is a minute):

```
by_var marker minute
A      0      1
A      0      2
A      1      3
B      0      1
B      0      2
B      1      3
```

From your data set by sorting by `by_var` and using a simple `data` step:

```
data my_data2;
  set my_data;
  by by_var;
  if first.by_var then minute = 0;
  minute+1;
  output;
run;
```

Or did you need to change something like this (with a time variable):

```
by_var marker time
A      0      12:34:01
A      0      12:34:59
A      0      12:35:01
A      0      12:36:12
A      1      12:36:50
B      0      12:34:01
B      0      12:34:09
B      0      12:34:59
B      0      12:36:12
B      1      12:37:50
```

To this:

```
by_var    marker      time         time2    minutes    Cumsum_minutes

  A          0      12:34:01           .       0           0
  A          0      12:34:59    12:34:01       0           0
  A          0      12:35:01    12:34:59       1           1
  A          0      12:36:12    12:35:01       1           2
  A          1      12:36:50    12:36:12       0           2
  B          0      12:34:01    12:36:50       0           0
  B          0      12:34:09    12:34:01       0           0
  B          0      12:34:59    12:34:09       0           0
  B          0      12:36:12    12:34:59       2           2
  B          1      12:37:50    12:36:12       1           3
```

CODE:

```
data my_data;
  input by_var $ marker time time.;
  format time time.;
  cards;
  A 0 12:34:01
  A 0 12:34:59
  A 0 12:35:01
  A 0 12:36:12
  A 1 12:36:50
  B 0 12:34:01
  B 0 12:34:09
  B 0 12:34:59
  B 0 12:36:12
  B 1 12:37:50
  ;
run;

proc sort data=my_data;by by_var;run;

data final;
  set my_data;
  format time2 time.;
  by by_var;
  time2=lag(time);
  if first.by_var then do;
    minutes = 0;
    Cumsum_minutes = 0;
  end;
  else minutes=intck("minutes",time2,time);
  Cumsum_minutes+minutes;
run;
```